# CSS hover with an "a"

Tags: html, css

I ran across a nice way of doing a menu in CSS that includes a hover:

```
#cssmenu li:hover a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1010ff;
  border: 1px solid #13a0ff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #13a0ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #13a0ff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #13a0ff;
}
```

However, I'm trying to figure out what the "a" is doing in

```
#cssmenu li:hover a {
```

I see other references in  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp that have the a before the hover with a colon:

```
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Still learning CSS....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is changing the appearance of the child `<a>` tag when the parent `<li>` tag is hovered.

You can use this to change the appearance of multiple elements on a single element :hover, assuming they're children of the hovered element.

For example, take this html:

```
<div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <a href="#">Go Here"</a>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
div:hover{
    background:#cc0000;
}
div:hover p{
   font-weight:bold;
}
div:hover a{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

When the `<div>` is hovered, the `<div>` changes background color, the `<p>` text goes bold, and the `<a>` text color changes.

Comment: Thanks- that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

The li is the element being hovered. The a is the element being selected (when its ancestor li is hovered).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "being selected". Each item in the menu has "<li><a href="<whatever>.html"><span>About</span></a></li>".

Comment: @user792826 — A CSS selector selects an element to apply the CSS to. The selected element is that element.